# Regexp matching a string - positive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Regexp: `(?=(\d+))\w+\1`
String: `456x56`

Hi,

I am not getting the concept, how this regex matches "56x56" in the string "456x56".

1. The lookaround, (?=(\d+)), captures 456 and put into \1, for (\d+)

   The wordcharacter, \w+, matches the whole string("456x56")

   \1, which is 456, should be followed by \w+

   After backtracking the string, it should not find a match, as there is no "456" preceded by a word character

However the regexp matches 56x56.

Comment: Why are you using a lookahead for this?  Seems to me `^(\d+)\w+\1$` will work just as well.

Comment: Yeah.I was using lookahead to know the concept and how the regex engine works, when a lookahead is present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't anchor your regex, as has been said. Another problem is that `\w` also matches digits... Now look at how the regex engine proceeds to match with your input:

```
# begin
regex: |(?=(\d+))\w+\1
input: |456x56
# lookahead (first group = '456')
regex: (?=(\d+))|\w+\1
input: |456x56 
# \w+
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+|\1
input: 456x56|
# \1 cannot be satisfied: backtrack on \w+
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+|\1
input: 456x5|6 
# And again, and again... Until the beginning of the input: \1 cannot match
# Regex engine therefore decides to start from the next character:
regex: |(?=(\d+))\w+\1
input: 4|56x56
# lookahead (first group = '56')
regex: (?=(\d+))|\w+\1
input: 4|56x56
# \w+
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+|\1
input: 456x56|
# \1 cannot be satisfied: backtrack
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+|\1
input: 456x5|6
# \1 cannot be satisfied: backtrack
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+|\1
input: 456x|56
# \1 satified: match
regex: (?=(\d+))\w+\1|
input: 4<56x56>
```

Comment: This is nice. Which tool was used to analyse the regex with string?

Answer (score 7):

5) Regex engines concludes that it cannot find a match if it start searching from 4, so it skips one character and searches again. This time, it captures two digits into `\1` and ends up matching `56x56`

If you want to match only whole strings, use `^(?=(\d+))\w+\1$`

```
^ matches beginning of string
$ matches end of string
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it :). We know that there is no match for lookahead first group = '456'. Therefore instead of \w+ backtracking from the second position of string, the lookahead, being the first operation before \w+, adjusts/tracks its second group ='56', making the \w+ to make a match for the whole string "456x56". Why is it not happening this way. The lookahead is supposed to track for the next group, right?, before the \w+, as lookahead precedes. So should not there be two matches 456x56 and 56x56. The first, result of lookahead track, second one \w+ track

Comment: @Maneesh Check this page for better understanding of internals of regex engine w.r.t look around http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html Btw, have you tested this regex with strings like "44" and even "445453"?

Comment: @Maneesh See my answer below. I tried to detail what's happening. Or fge's answer which is particularly clear

Comment: @Ikuty. Yeah thanks. fge's answer was very clear. Not sure how can we generate the analysis that fge has put below.

Comment: @Maneesh You should probably accept that answer instead of mine :)

Answer (score 0):

The points you listed are almost entirely, but not quite, wrong!

```
 1) The group  (?=(\d+)) matches a sequence of one or more digits
    not necessarily 456 
 2) \w captures only characters, not digits 
 3) \1 the is a back reference to the match in the group
```

So the role expression means find a sequence of digits followed by s sequence of word characters with are followed by the same sequence that was found in front of the characters. Hence the match 56x56.

Comment: @Mithrandir \w matches any digits,any characters, and underscore

Answer (score 0):

Well that's what makes it a positive lookahead

```
 (?=(\d+))\w+\1
```

You are correct when you say the first \d+ will match 456, so \1 must also be 456, but if that's the case: the expression won't match the string.

The only common characters of before the x and after the x are 56, and that's what it will do to get a positive match.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+` is greedy and backtracks as necessary. The lookahead `(?=(\d+))` will match 456 then 56 if the regex fails then 6 if the regex fails. First attempt: 456. It matches, the group 1 contains 456. Then we have `\w+` which is greedy and takes 456x56, there is nothing left but we still have to match `\1` i.e. 456. Thus: failure. Then `\w+` backtraks one step at a time till we get to the beginning of the regex. And it still fails.

We consume a character from the string. Next backtrack is trying to lookahead match with substring 56. it matches and the group 1 contains 56. `\w+` matches until the end of the string and gets 456x56 and then we try to match 56: failure. So `\w+` bactracks until we have 56 left in the string and then we have a global match and regex success.

You should try it with regex buddy debug mode.

Comment: @fge You said the same thing below. Saw it too late.